# Why does one users’s Outlook in Office 365 randomly get blurry with the characters appearing misaligned?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have one user who is on Windows 10 (Build 19044) with Office 365. The user’s view in Outlook gets blurry with the characters appearing misaligned. The user must exit and sometimes reboot for the view to reset properly. His view in Outlook will be fine for a view days before the problem reoccurs.

This appears to happen randomly and does not happen anywhere else for the user outside of Outlook. In addition, no other user in our organization has this problem. I have confirmed that his version of Office 365 is up to date.

The user will be away in a week. So, I am doing my homework in advance. It is difficult for me to work on this user’s computer during the day and he normally takes it with him overnight.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what it looks like when this occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Have the user done any specific operations before the issue occurs? Such as installing any add-ins? Or anything else?

In order to further confirm whether the problem is related to the user's account, it is recommended that you try to configure his account in another user's working outlook client to check whether it works normally.

If the issue only related to the specific user's Outlook client, please refer to the following steps for troubleshooting:

1.Considering the influence of some views, please try a command to reset the view settings: win+R> type: outlook /cleanviews.(This command will delete all custom view settings. If you need to keep other view settings, please remember to back up.)

2.Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

3.If this is still the issue in safe mode, it is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

4.considering that it would also be affected when the outlook program itself is damaged. It is recommended that you try to [fix the Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas :

- Check for an installed Outlook extension unique to that computer
- Repair or reinstall Office.

Comment: Why the downvote, if I might ask?